# Data form $scope not display in view (page) in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm new in Angular and I have problem with display data on view page. I how no idea why with this is problem, because all data from API and form controller in console.log show correct.

My controller:

```
'use strict';

var pokayokaCtr = angular.module( 'pokayokaCtr' , [ 'ngRoute' ] );



// -------------------------------------------
//                  DRAWINGS
// -------------------------------------------

pokayokaCtr.controller( 'drawings' , [ '$scope' , '$http', function( $scope, $http ){


    $http.get( 'api/admin/drawings/get' ).
    success( function( data ){
        $scope.drawings = data;
    }).error( function(){
        console.log( 'Błąd pobrania pliku z bazy danych! Drawings' );
    });

}]);

pokayokaCtr.controller( 'drawingCreate' , [ '$scope' , '$http' , '$timeout', function( $scope , $http, $timeout){

    $scope.createDrawing = function ( drawing ) {


        $http.post('api/admin/drawings/create', {
            drawing : drawing
        }).success(function(){

            $timeout(function(){
                $scope.success = false;

                $scope.drawing = {};
            } , 1500 );
            console.log($scope.drawing);

        }).error(function(){
            console.log('Błąd połączenia z bazą danych.')
        });

    };

}]);


pokayokaCtr.controller( 'pokayokes' , [ '$scope' , '$http', '$routeParams', function( $scope, $http, $routeParams ){


    // var drawingId = $routeParams.id;
    // $scope.id = drawingId;

    var pokayokeName = $routeParams.name;
    $scope.name = pokayokeName;



    $http.get( 'api/admin/pokayokes/get/' + pokayokeName ).
    success( function( data ){
        $scope.pokayokes = data;
        // var test = data.ile_py
        // console.log( test );
    }).error( function(){
        console.log( 'Błąd pobrania pliku z bazy danych poka-yoke' );
    });



}]);

pokayokaCtr.filter('rangeFilter', function() {
     return function(input, total) {
        total = parseInt(total);
        for (var i=6; i<=total; i++)
          input.push(i);
        return input;
  };
});



// -------------------------------------------
//                  ARTICLES
// -------------------------------------------

pokayokaCtr.controller( 'articles' , [ '$scope' , '$http', function( $scope, $http  ){


    $http.get( 'api/admin/articles/get' ).
    success( function( data ){
        $scope.articles = data;
    }).error( function(){
        console.log( 'Błąd pobrania pliku z bazy danych! articles' );
    });

}]);

pokayokaCtr.controller( 'articleCreatePart1' , [ '$scope' ,'$routeParams', 'pantonsLoader', function( $scope, $routeParams, pantonsLoader ){


    var drawingName = $routeParams.name_rys;
    $scope.name_rys = drawingName;

    pantonsLoader(function (data){
        $scope.pantons = data;
        console.log(data);
    });


    $scope.articleCreatePart1 = function (article) {


        $http.post('api/admin/articles/create' + drawingName, {
            article : article
        }).success(function(){

            $timeout(function(){
                $scope.success = false;

                $scope.article = {};
            } , 1500 );
            console.log($scope.article);

        }).error(function(){
            console.log('Błąd połączenia z bazą danych.')
        });

    };

}]);

pokayokaCtr.factory('pantonsLoader', ['$http', function($http) {


    return function () {

        $http.get( 'api/admin/pantons/get' ).
        success( function( data ){
            console.log(data);
        }).error( function(){
            console.log( 'Błąd pobrania pliku z bazy danych! pantons' );
        });
    };
}])
```

Part form page view in html (this part is in ng-view):

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="flat-panel">
                <div class="flat-panel-header">
                    <h3 class="page-header">Choose panton's color </h3>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                            <label for="nazwaRysunku">Search name:  </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="szukaj..." ng-model="search.nazwa_pan">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="flat-panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12" >
                        <div class="p-pantony" >
                            <label ng-repeat="panton in pantons | filter : search" class="checkbox-inline" style="width: 100px; float: left; border-bottom: 10px solid rgb({{panton.R}}, {{panton.G}}, {{panton.B}} ) margin:0 10px 10px 0;">
                                <!-- <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="article.pantonP" > x -->
                                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="panton.nazwa_pan"  ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" > {{panton.nazwa_pan}} 
                            </label>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div>    
                </div> <!-- .flat-panel-body -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- /.row -->
```

I have same problem in another file - I can't use normal binding, but ng-repeat is working.

---

**12.08.2015 - edit:**

I made filter and added to controller, my code below:

```
pokayokaCtr.controller( 'pokayokes' , [ '$scope' , '$http', '$routeParams', function( $scope, $http, $routeParams, numberColFilter ){

    var pokayokeName = $routeParams.name;
    $scope.name = pokayokeName;

    var number = $routeParams.number;
    $scope.number = number; 

    $http.get( 'api/admin/pokayokes/get/' + pokayokeName + '/'+ number).
    success( function( data ){
        $scope.pokayokes = data;
    }).error( function(){
        console.log( 'Error database connect!' );
    });


}]);

pokayokaCtr.filter('numberColFilter', function() {
     return function(items,number) {

        var range = [];

        var start = 4;
        var end = start + number;

        for (var i = start; i < end; i++)
        {
            range.push(items[i]);
        }

        return range;
  };
});
```

I checked breakpoints and 'number' in controller and filter is okay, the number has number, but 'end' and 'i' are undefined. Why is that? Is this filter good written? Because when I added this filter to html on page is displaying '[]'.

I added this filter like this (code below), this is okay?

```
<thead>
       <tr>
           <th>Lp.</th>
           <th>Image</th>
           <th>Name <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i> </th>
           <th >Colors in article</th>
           <th ng-repeat="pokayoke in pokayokes">{{$index + 1 | numberColFilter }}</th>
       </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
       <tr ng-repeat="pokayoke in pokayokes" >
           <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
           <td><a href=""> <i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i> View</a></td>
           <td>{{pokayoke.name_dra</i> </td>
           <td>{{pokayoke.colors_art}}</td>
           <td ng-repeat="num in pokayoke" >{{ num | numberColFilter}}</td>   
       </tr>                               
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you've got a textbox that you're using so the user can search for an filter by a term and this is storing to `$scope.search.nazwa_pan`. However, in the filter, you're having it filter simply against `$scope.search` so it's not actually doing a compare as you might be looking for.

Edit (to match the updated question):

In the first line of your controller, there's no need for a reference to the filter in your controller.

```
pokayokaCtr.controller( 'pokayokes' , [ '$scope' , '$http', '$routeParams', function( $scope, $http, $routeParams, numberColFilter )
```

should be

```
pokayokaCtr.controller( 'pokayokes' , [ '$scope' , '$http', '$routeParams',  function( $scope, $http, $routeParams)
```

Also, your filter is expecting two arguments to be passed in, but you're only providing it with the items to iterate through - you're not proving it with the 'number' argument at all. Rather, you'd need to do something like the following (in that the following '4' is the value being passed into the second argument of your filter function).

```
<td ng-repeat="num in pokayoke" >{{ num | numberColFilter: 4}}</td>
```

Alternatively, if you're storing a number in $scope.argumentNumber, use the following instead.

```
<td ng-repeat="num in pokayoke" >{{ num | numberColFilter: argumentNumber}}</td>
```

Comment: I want to the searching will be by only in column where I have names in database and on another site it works ok.I deleted all search filters and still the list not want display on ma site. So I think it must be something else...

Comment: If you insert a breakpoint in the JavaScript, do you see that it's actually successfully returning data in the response in your factory?

Comment: I'm deleting all filters which were on site to not disturb, I checked by breakpoints (how you said above) in the JavaScript  in controllers file and everything is okay, the data is display in debugger, but on the site is still not displaying....

Comment: Glancing at it, I see that in the first line of your updated controller, you don't have the string reference to the injected filter, just the object.

Comment: I'm not passing 'number' agrument because I want to the number argument will be the same as number form pokayokes controller but I don't know how pass it to filter?

Comment: And when I copy your answer to controller and html I have this error:"Error: [$injector:unpr]"(Unknown provider: numberColFilterProvider <- numberColFilter <- pokayokes") in console. What that mean?

Comment: To your first question, you'd pass in the name of the variable on $scope instead of the '4' in the last line of my answer. To the second question, I mistyped - no need for a filter injected into the controller.

Comment: Ok, I changed. Now I have this error: "Error: $rootScope:inprog
Action Already In Progress."  and I think I have something wrong in my API.  It's must be with passing data, because when I make console.log(data), in the output is array not json format...

Comment: That sounds like you're trying to do something while a $digest is in progress. Remove that and see if it'll take.

Comment: I improved passing the date form API (almost - I have one result but should be more, more info in other mine question). And when I'm making breakpoints, the arguments and for loop is working ok, but the in the array I have undefined elements and on site crazy things happen... :)

Comment: Now I have bigger problem because on my site are about 300 or more rows and columns with null. When I erase filter from ng-repeat I have all in one column and in each row one string from my result. Where can be something wrong? You can see [here](http://sinke.vot.pl/testy/py/another-problem.jpg) <- In this example should be 11 columns and 3 rows with result form API.